# Get current page title

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am making react native expo app and i need your help.
I have structure:

> main.js => page1.js => page2.js

When i move from main.js to page1.js in createStackNavigator i write title of header of page1.js, but in page1.js i hide the header of page1.js and i have all ok, but when i move to page2.js i have 3 headers!!!!

One of them i hide in page2.js but one other header i do not how to hide, because 1 header is coming from main.js but second from page1.js and i need to hide this header from main.js but if i hide it i will not have header in page1.js.
I want when i navigate to page2.js from page1.js i send data to main.js createStackNavigator. How i can do this??
Code:

```html
// main.js createStackNavigator:

export default createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: Main,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      },
    },
    Page1: {
      screen: Page1,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: "Page1",
    }),
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Main',
  }
);

// Page1.js createStackNavigator:


export default createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: Page1,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      },
    },
    Page2: {
      screen: Page2,
       navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: "Text",
    }),
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Main',
  }
);

// Page2:

export default createStackNavigator(
    {
      Main: {
        screen: Page2,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Main',
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating rout names, `Main` is used 3 times,
also `page1` and `page2` have 2 different routes each,

solution is to create call createStackNavigator in seperate file or in app.js like

```
export default createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: Main,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      },
    },
    Page1: {
      screen: Page1,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: "Page1",
    }),
    },
    Page2: {
      screen: Page2,
       navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: "Text",
    }),
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Main',
  }
);
```

now all the screens will have same header and you can change the title in [navigationOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options.html)

Comment: so i need to create file where i will past this code. But what i need to export in file main,page1,page2.js? There i have button that navigate to each page, i need to past this code one more time in each pages???

Comment: for each page you should export the screen like `export default class Main extends Component{}` and navigation like in my answer

Comment: use the navigation component to create app container to use in app.js ```const AppContainer = createAppContainer(Navigation);```

Comment: look at https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/nested-navigationoptions-title-v3